# How to enforce no "www" on multi domain site?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multi domain site, meaning multiple domains are pointing to my server.

The common way people say to enforce no `www` in a site's URL is usually something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

However, this code relies on the domain being `example.com` Is there a way to make it work for any domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to make it work for any domain.  It just replaces the `example.com` with a liberal match `(.+)` and substitutes it in the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]
```